# How did the smoothness of map into R^m transfer to the smoothness of map into R

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The following is a proof from the book Introduction to manifolds by Tu ( Page 63)

[image]

[image]

I did not understand the highlighted step. Please explain.

Comment: It's exactly what he says: the definition. A map $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is smooth if and only if its component functions $f_1, \dots, f_m$ are smooth.

Comment: ohh ok I get it. Thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice: 
$$Fo\phi ^{-1}:\mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^m$$
More precisely domain is subset of $\mathbf R^n$ and n is dimension of manifold, so when this map that you've see in multivariable calculus is $C^{\infty}$ in a usual definition? When all his component functions that are $\mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R$ are $C^{\infty}$.